# Socket event fires that data is available in WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(), but the data is not actually there

Tags: c++, windows

I have a thread that is receiving data on the socket. I am using `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()` since I have another custom event that is used to wake up the thread at the end of the program.

Here is how the socket is setup with the first event in the event array:

```
int ret = 0;
u_long iMode = 0;
ret = ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &iMode);
if (ret != NO_ERROR)
    return some_enum_error;
else if (WSAEventSelect(sock, events[0], FD_READ) != 0)
    return some_enum_error;
```

Now, we go to wait for the event:

```
bool result = false;
DWORD ret;
WSANETWORKEVENTS NetworkEvents;

ret = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(2, events, FALSE, WSA_INFINITE, FALSE);
if (ret == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0) {
    WSAEnumNetworkEvents(sock, events[0], &NetworkEvents);
    result = true;
}
```

and now, read the data with:

```
recv(sock, (char*)buf, static_cast<size_t>(len), flags)
```

This works, most of the time. However, if the network has a big latency, I am seeing issues where the event fires but there is no data available from the `recv()` function. Once I hit this issue, I added the code to go back and `recv()` again after some time, and the data is there just fine.

Any ideas why this happens? How can I make this work without the additional poll?

Comment: What is the result code returned by `recv`?

Comment: I am not really familiar with `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents`, but standard `select` / `poll` only guarantee that the socket operation will not be blocked. Also, when you say 'no data' I imagine `recv` returned 0?

Comment: Is your ioctlsocket(FIONBIO) call intended to set the socket to non-blocking mode?  Because at it is, I think it’s setting the socket to blocking-mode (iMode==0, aka non-blocking mode disabled, aka blocking mode)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner What you say is true. However, the subsequent `WSAEventSelect()` will force the socket into a non-blocking mode, per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaeventselect): "*The `WSAEventSelect` function automatically sets socket `s` to nonblocking mode, regardless of the value of `lNetworkEvents`.*"

Comment: @SergeyA Standard `select`/`poll` is just a status-reporting function and like all status-reporting functions, makes no guarantees about what will or won't be the case at some future point. (Many years ago, this incorrect assumption lead to a very serious denial of service attack on the `inetd` service in many Linux distributions.)

Comment: recv returned WSAEWOULDBLOCK. I assume that this means that the data is not available and it would block waiting for data

Comment: [The documentation for WSAEventSelect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaeventselect) explicitly calls out that "a robust application must be prepared for the possibility that the event object is set and it issues a Windows Sockets call that returns WSAEWOULDBLOCK immediately."

Comment: @RaymondChen thank you for pointing that out. Further in documentation it states: Consider the following sequence:
1. The transport provider receives 100 bytes of data on socket s and causes WS2_32.DLL to record the FD_READ network event and set the associated event object.
2. The application issues recv(s, buffptr, 50, 0) to read 50 bytes.
3. The transport provider causes WS2_32.DLL to record the FD_READ network event and sets the associated event object again since there is still data to be read.
Out of here it is clear that after WSAEWOULDBLOCK I just need to wait for event again

Comment: @DavidSchwartz wrong. From the man of select: `The file descriptors in this set are watched to see if they are ready for reading.  A file descriptor is ready for reading if a read operation will not block...`

Comment: @SergeyA That's exactly what I said. They are status reporting functions that don't make future guarantees. By "will not block", it doesn't mean "won't block in the future", it means will not block at the moment the status is reported. There is no future guarantee. (Also, you'll notice that it is not specific about *what* read operation will not block. There is more than one possible read operation you could do. It doesn't say that any possible read operation will not block.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz citation needed. In particular, you claim that a it is possible for a normal read operation to block on a socket which was returned by poll/select as readable. I think, this claim is unorthodox and needs proof.

Comment: @SergeyA The claim that any status reporting operation guarantees that a particular future operation will produce a particular result is the unorthodox one. In any event, it's trivial to produce the result I describe on many operating systems. For example: open a UDP socket, disable UDP checksums, select on the socket, send a datagram with an invalid checksum, wait for the select hit, enable UDP checksums, call read. You are claiming something is *guaranteed* merely because you couldn't think of a way that guarantee could fail.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz or you can have a hit from select, close the socket, open a new one, get the same fd and try to read from it. Or make socket non-blocking, call select, put it back to blocking mode (under some implementations, select on non-blocking sockets signal immediately). Obviously, it has it's boundaries. I maintain that under normal circumstances (i.e. no one altering fundamental properties of the socket in between those operations) you are guaranteed not to block after select fired. If you have any proof to the contrary (ideally, a snippet of code which would demonstrate it, but an

Comment: @DavidSchwartz (continuing) but an article in the reviewed magazine would do either - I will be very grateful if you share it, but otherwise, have it good day.

Comment: @SergeyA The example I gave didn't involve modifying any fundamental properties of the socket. Whether or not UDP checksums are enabled is not a socket property. Do you have a source for the claim that we are guaranteed that a UDP datagram won't be dropped after it causes a `select` or `poll` hit?